# Replacing gzipped files into zipped files

Tags: unix, directory, zip, gzip

On my Unix server, I have a ~2500 gzipped text files in various folders. I need to replace them from gzipped to zipped.

I'd like to do that possibly with Unix `find`.

```
find . -name *.gz
./folder/download/All/fil_all.bed.gz
./folder/download/All/nr_all.bed.gz
./folder/download/All/fil_public.bed.gz
./folder/download/All/nr_public.bed_m.gz
./folder/download/All/nr_public.bed.gz
```

For instance `find . -name *.gz -exec ...`

However I am not sure, what would be the one liner for the gunzip , zip process.

Answer (score 0):

On most unixes you have `gzcat` which sends gunzipped output to stdout. However it'll be hard to get that properly zipped in a one-liner (you can do it but you'd have no name for the zipped contents, as they come from stdin). So I guess the best is to make a small script and invoke that from the find.

e.g. rudimentary `gz2zip.sh` (not tested):

```
#!/bin/ksh
# input = $1 = gzipped input file name ending in .gz
BASENAME=$(basename $1 .gz)          # short name without path or extension
ZIPNAME=$(dirname $1)/$BASENAME.zip  # full name with .zip instead of .gz
TMPDIR=/tmp/gz2zip.$$                # place to unpack .gz in and pack .zip from
mkdir $TMPDIR
gzcat $1 > $TMPDIR/$BASENAME
(cd $TMPDIR; zip $ZIPNAME ./*)
rm -rf $TMPDIR
```

Then use it inside find:

```
find .  -name "*.gz" -exec gz2zip.sh {} \;
```